# Sharing Variables Across Different Activities In Android Studio

Tags: android, class, variables, global, sharing

I Have an Activity called Main2Activity, and it consists of a variable "double result1 " which is set equal to an expression. It looks like this:

`double result1 = n1 * 2 - 29;` (Where n1 is an input given by the user)

I'm trying to use this variable in another class called MainActivityEnd. I tried this:

```
double finalResult = Main2Activity.result1 * 4;
```

When I print result1 in Main2Activity using `setText` it prints the correct value.

But when I print `finalResult` in `MainActivityEnd` using `setText` It always prints `0.0`

Is there a reason for this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might want to show the actual code you tried.

Comment: pass your double in your intent you use to start your activity

Comment: Either pass your variable in the Intent you use to start the other Activity or use SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thank you all for the Help!

Answer (score 2):

If activities are in the same flow, you should use the following Android way - intents. Simply put, Intent is Android's way of changing values between activities when they are launched in sequential order.

So you should do the following in Main2Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivityEnd.class);
intent.putExtra("name", variable);
startActivity(intent);
```

where Main2Activity starts MainActivityEnd. The Intent is filled with the data MainActivityEnd needs, which in this case is "variable".

Afterwards you should catch the Intent in MainActivityEnd onCreate() method like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
double finalResult = intent.getDoubleExtra("name", 0);
```

where "name" is the same name that was given in Main2Activity and 0 is a default value if there's wasn't a double value attached to Intent in Main2Activity.

That's the most common usage of this behaviour in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intents` or `SharedPreferences` like other people has already mentioned here.

If however you are planning to put some global logic (like methods) then use Application class.

You can extend Application class like this:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
    public double result1 = 29;
}
```

And then in any in your Activities:

```
YourApplication app = (YourApplication) this.getApplication();
System.out.printl(app.result1);
```

Make sure that you named your application class properly, it should be `[YOUR_APP_NAME]Application`. And also don't forget to put your new application class into the `manifest`:

```
<application 
    android:name=".YourApplication"
```

Comment: This is a horrible approach. You should use SharedPreferences instead.

Comment: There are two ways this can bite you: Android kills your process and your activities are later recreated and find the global state uninitialized; or Android *doesn't* kill your process when your last activity finishes, and global state carries over to the next launch of the app.  Global state is evil, but it's especially evil on Android.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede is there an alternative for extending Application then if you want to have a global place for your logic (methods)?

Comment: If you must use global state, putting it in `Application` is no worse than putting it anywhere else.  Just be aware of how it can cause problems.  And note that a member of the `Application` instance is subtly different from a `static` global.  In practice, the `Application` instance has the same lifetime as the process and VM, and therefore the same lifetime as `static` fields, but AFAIK this is not documented and therefore may change without warning.